# Can't update Xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to update my xml file using this code.

```
int i;
XmlNodeList list = xdoc.SelectNodes("Sale/SalesLines/SalesLine");

foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        node.SelectSingleNode("VatAmount").InnerText = Convert.ToString(datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
        xdoc.Save(path);
    }                    
}
```

So first of all I'm trying to update the xml file using the integer data from my grid. Now there are 2 salesline nodes in my xml file. The above code does update the values in that node but its sets both the elements value as the last element that was read using the loop. It reads both(there are 2 values read and updated in the file) the values but updates only the last read value in both those nodes vatamount element. Btw count holds the count of rows in the grid. Can anyone help me fix this. I really need this solved.

Ok. Guys Please forgive me. My co-employee saw my code and he said not to use that code but to use this.

```
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView view = (DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView)gridControl1.FocusedView;
view.PostEditor();
view.RefreshData();

DataTable table = ((DataView)gridView1.DataSource).ToTable();
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    //textBox8.Text += Convert.ToString(dr["NewVATAmt"]);
    foreach (XmlNode node in list)
    {
        node.SelectSingleNode("VatAmount").InnerText = Convert.ToString(dr["NewVATAmt"]);
    }    
}
xdoc.Save(path);
```

So I'm now using a dev express grid control instead of a datagrid. And with this code i'm facing the same problem. Please go through this code ad try to suggest a fix. Please.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Do you know what the issue is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want then you need to keep a counter out of the `foreach` loop (not a loop inside a loop). Something like this (notice that you should still check if `Rows[i]` exists or you get an exception).

```
int i = 0;
foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{
   node.SelectSingleNode("VatAmount").InnerText = Convert.ToString(datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
   i++;
}

xdoc.Save(path);
```

Also, you probably want to save the document only once after you updated all the nodes.

UPDATE: for the second sample you should follow a similar pattern.

```
DataTable table = ((DataView)gridView1.DataSource).ToTable();
int i = 0;
foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{
    node.SelectSingleNode("VatAmount").InnerText = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[i]["NewVATAmt"]);
    i++;    
}
xdoc.Save(path);
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Your code works. Can u suggest a fix for the other code?

Comment: Well, you should have been able to use the same pattern for your second sample too.